# awk field separtor

Tags: awk

I have a file like this :
[image]

and I want the output as:

[image]

I tried using awk :

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } { sub("\\..*", "", $1); print }'
```

and it prints the first id ENST.
But when I change it to:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } { sub("\\..*", "", $5); print }'
```

it doesnt work.

What is wrong that I am doing here. Kindly help.

Comment: could you please provide a text-format toy example (or first few lines) of your input file? that would help to quickly see an application of your tests with awk.

Comment: done.KIndly see

Comment: thanks, although i meant more in an easily copy-pastable text format (not a screenshot) in a code snippet for example, same you used to write in your awk lines

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to only show the fifth id from the first field, the following Perl script should work:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?)\t//; @F=split("\\|", $1); print(@F[4]."\t")' input.tsv > output.tsv
```

Explanation of the Perl code:

1. Loop over the lines in the input file (this is enabled by the command-line option `-p`)
2. Remove everything up to the first tab character from the input line, and save the removed part (excluding tab character) into the grouping variable `$1` [identified by brackets].
3. Split variable `$1` at the pipe character, `|`, saving the split components into the array `@F`
4. Print the fifth field [0,1,2,3,**4**] from the array `@F` [without a line break at the end]
5. Print the remainder of the input line (this is also enabled by the command-line option `-p`)

Comment: DDX11L1-202 is in the very first line of the excel document 5th character in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You need the first column's 6th component when split by `|` and then the remaining columns of the file where `\t` is the delimiter. Use awk.

```
awk -F "\t" -vOFS="\t" 'NR==1 {print} NR>1{split($1,arr,"|"); print arr[6],$2,$3,$4,$5}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this in libreoffice calc using text to columns (data menu)

If you want to use awk (or maybe gawk) you could use capture groups; but rather that mess around with a fairly complex regex I'd probably do it in two stages like below

```
awk -F"|" '{print $5,$0}' OFS="\t" your_file|\
awk -F"\t" '{print $1,substr($0,index($0,$3))}'
```

The second awk prints everything except field 2

Comment: DDX11L1-202 1657|lncRNA| it retains the other columns with pipes.